# SQL query is not returning values even if there are values in mysql Table

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I got this function:

```
private function _loadColumnRights() {

            $db = Zend_Registry::get('db');

            // Create the select query
            $select = $db->select()
                        ->from('account_columns', array(
                            'accountId'
                        ))
                        ->where('accountId = ?', $this->getId()); 

            // Fetch the data
            $row = $db->fetchRow($select);
            if($row != null) {
                $this->setColumns($row['columns']);
            }
            else {
                $this->setColumns('');
            }
        }
```

I search for the `accountID = '128'`

My table looks like this:

accountId | columns

and at row with `accountId = '128'` I got a value like this 'orderdate,ref-corlido,item-no,partid,item-description,quantity-value,unit-of-measurement,acquisition-value-order-line,sales-value-order-line,markup,due-date,status,direct-delivery,out-of-scope,non-compliant,memo,request-document,documents'

If I in PHP manually execute this SQL statement:

```
SELECT * FROM `account_columns` WHERE `accountId` = '128'
```

Then I get result..

my Code also goes in to this if:

```
if($row != null) {
            $this->setColumns($row['columns']);
        }
```

But the value of `$row['columns'`] is empty.. If I perform a var_dump on my view on this getter then i get empty values

If I change `$row['columns']`) to :

```
$this->setColumns($row['accountId']);
```

then I get the 128 value..
But I don't get the column values.. How come?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you only ask for one column in the result row. :)

You only as k for `accountId`...

```
    private function _loadColumnRights() {

        $db = Zend_Registry::get('db');

        // Create the select query
        $select = $db->select()

                    // THERE IS YOU ERROR :)
                    // THE SECOND PARAMETER IS AN ARRAY OF RESULT COLUMNS
                    ->from('account_columns', array(
                        //'accountId',  <-- Your error :)
                        '*' // use this if you want all columns back
                        //'columns' // or add this column name
                    ))


                    ->where('accountId = ?', $this->getId()); 

        // Fetch the data
        $row = $db->fetchRow($select);
        if($row != null) {
            $this->setColumns($row['columns']);
        }
        else {
            $this->setColumns('');
        }
    }
```

P.S.: You really should use another name for the "columns" colmn... :)
Look at the list of reserved words and keywords... don't use them for column or table names. :)

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html

Have a great day!

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer and a big + pointing good out where the error is :)